# How to save the history of the recently clicked buttons in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a piano app which plays sounds when pressing any button, here's a snippet of the code in main.dart :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static AudioCache player = AudioCache();

  Widget myTone(Color myColor, int myNumber) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
          hoverColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          color: myColor,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              player.play('note$myNumber.wav');
            });
          },
          child: null),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Set landscape orientation
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Piano Everywhere'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              myTone(Colors.black, 1),
              myTone(Colors.black54, 2),
              myTone(Colors.black45, 3),
              myTone(Colors.black38, 4),
              myTone(Colors.black26, 5),
              myTone(Colors.black12, 6),
              myTone(Colors.white12, 7)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I would like to save the history of which notes were played recently. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array to store the tone number that has been pressed. I usually use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for global variables so you can show the updated history list whenever it has been changed.

In my case I probably will save in List.

```
List<Int> pressedToneList = [];
```

And in the onPressed in your myTone widget, append the myNumber in the list every press:

```
Widget myTone(Color myColor, int myNumber) {
return Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
      hoverColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      color: myColor,
      onPressed: () {
        pressedToneList.add(myNumber);
        setState(() {
          player.play('note$myNumber.wav');
        });
      },
      child: null),
);
```

}

If you use provider, you can create a class that stores the array, something like this:

```
class RecentClickedHistory extends ChangeNotifier {
    List<int> list;
    
    RecentClickedHistory();

    add(int myNumber) {
        list.add(myNumber);
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Use RecentClickedHistory.add(myNumber) instead of pressedToneList.add(myNumber); if you're using provider.

Read the provider docs about Listeners if you want to go down that route, or you can reply here and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: Thank you! I added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362827/sending-data-to-firebase-each-time-button-is-clicked-in-flutter . any help would be appreciated! @nickypangers